# HttpClient with Authentication returns 404. Why?

Tags: c#, rest, http, windows-8.1, httpclient

I have an API that needs authentication with username and password. I can't figure out why my code fails and the response is 404, when I'm doing a GET method and give the actual credentials:

```
NetworkCredential networkCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("adminUN", "mypassword");
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.PreAuthenticate = true;
handler.Credentials = networkCredentials;

httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(GlobalDeclarations.strURL);
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: 404 means the URL is wrong. Authentication errors return 401.

Comment: Is this a WebAPI and if so, what happens if you set a breakpoint in your controller method? Most probably the routing settings or your Url is wrong.

Comment: No, the URL is fine. I pasted it into a browser and it works fine. Could it be a certificate problem? Because obviously my Windows phone device cannot resolve this self-signed certificate and the mobile IE blocks the page?